# What is the % in this RegEx within this Lighthttpd configuration?

Tags: regex, lighttpd

```
  $HTTP["scheme"] == "http" {
    $HTTP["host"] =~ "^(.*)$" {
      url.redirect = ("^/folder/(.*)$" => "https://%1/$1")
    }
  }
```

Obviously, the %1 is inserting the host - but where is getting it from? My first thought is in from the line above it where it is matching against the host, but that doesn't seem right.

Is %1 is a built-in placeholder for the hostname or is it coming from the previous "host" match?

Comment: May be http://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/1/wiki/docs_modredirect will help.

Comment: What language is that? Please help others provide you with assistance by tagging your question appropriately.

Comment: It's not a language per say. It's a lighthttpd configuration for which I tagged it and put in the title.

Comment: @RohitJain Submit an answer where you quote the part about %1 and I will accept.

Comment: @doremi.. There you go. Added something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation of [`url.redirect`](http://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/1/wiki/docs_modredirect): -

> Note that the "%1" in the url.redirect target refers to the
>   parenthesized subexpression in the conditional regexp (.*). It does
>   not necessarily have the meaning that "%1" would have in
>   evhost.path-pattern (where it would mean 'top-level domain'). If
>   url.redirect is specified within a regex conditional, % patterns are
>   replaced by the corresponding groups from the condition regex. %1 is
>   replaced with the first subexpression, %2 with the second, etc. %0 is
>   replaced by the entire substring matching the regexp. See above and
>   below for examples using % patterns.